# Resample factors are too large

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, resampling

I have a large vector of recorded data which I need to resample. The problem I encounter is that when using `resample`, I get the following error:

> ??? Error using ==> upfirdn at 82 The product of the downsample factor
>   Q and the upsample factor P must be less than 2^31.

Now, I understand why this is happening - my two sampling rates are very close together, so the integer factors need to be quite large (something like 73999/74000). Unfortunately this means that the appropriate filter can't be created by MATLAB. I also tried resampling just up, with the intention of then resampling down, but there is not enough memory to do this to even 1 million samples of data (mine is 93M).

What other methods could I use to properly resample this data?

Comment: Is it possible to apply `resample` twice?

Comment: @Kamtal How would you apply it twice? Use smaller ratios that, when done in succession, are equivalent to what I desire? I've tried doing the simplest version of that, starting with upsampling only, then downsampling, but I do not have enough memory for that.

Comment: Write your own? [This paper](http://www.ucalgary.ca/engo_webdocs/SpecialPublications/KIS%2001/PDF/1002.PDF) provides a good description of how to implement a robust resampler.

Comment: what is the length of your data?

Comment: @Kamtal About 93 million, as I said in my question.

Comment: With `93 million` samples and `73999 / 74000` re-sampling you will lose about `1300` samples. Even if you could manage to design that filer, most of your samples won't change value. So I suggest you choose a subset like `1 million` and re-sample it with `0.9987`. would it work?

Comment: How small a dataset do you have to get down to in order for it to work? Will it work on ~100,000 samples?

Answer (score 0):

An interpolated polyphase FIR filter can be used to interpolate just the new set of sample points without using an upsampling+downsampling process.

But if performance is completely unimportant, here's a [Quick and Dirty windowed-Sinc interpolator in Basic](http://www.nicholson.com/rhn/dsp.html#3).

Answer (score 0):

here's my code, I hope it helps :

```
function resig = resamplee(sig,upsample,downsample)
if upsample*downsample<2^31
    resig = resample(sig,upsample,downsample);
else
    
    sig1half=sig(1:floor(length(sig)/2));
    sig2half=sig(floor(length(sig)/2):end);
    resig1half=resamplee(sig1half,floor(upsample/2),length(sig1half));
    resig2half=resamplee(sig2half,upsample-floor(upsample/2),length(sig2half));
    resig=[resig1half;resig2half];

end
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).